# How to compute the convex conjugate of norm raised to the power of $2$, $f(x) = \|x\|^2/2$

Tags: convex-optimization, subgradient

How would one find the conjugate of the following :
$$f(x) = \|x\|^2 /2$$ 
The conjugate function is defined as $ f^*(y) = \max_x y^Tx - f(x)$

I am stuck at how I can derive the explicit form for $x$.

So far, here are my steps:

To maximize I take the derivative and set to $0$.

$$f'(x) = y - \partial\|x\| \cdot \|x\| = 0$$

$$\partial\|x\| = y/\|x\| $$

Edit : $\|x\|$ is any norm here. Not just the 2-norm.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: I don't think this is so easy to do in general.  The conjugate for a norm is known as the dual norm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm.  For the $\ell_p$ norm the dual is the $\ell_q$ norm with $1/p+1/q=1$, for the nuclear norm the dual is the operator norm and so forth.  Note that norms are not differentiable at zero, so to do the maximization you need to use the sub-gradient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fenchel Conjugate of a norm squared](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120885/fenchel-conjugate-of-a-norm-squared)

Answer (score 4):

For norm, conjugate is indicator of unit ball for dual norm.

See [Conjugate Functions](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/conj.pdf) at page 7-9:

[image]

By [Lieven Vandenberghe](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Image - http://i.imgur.com/d0vc1B7.png.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, because the question asks for the conjugate of $\|x\|^2$, not $\|x\|$.

Comment: This answer is so bad even if you are trying to compute the conjugate of $\|x\|$. Beginners do not look at $\|x\|$ and then immediately try to do some analysis on the dual norm $\|y\|_\ast$.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I transcribed a proof from Example 3.27 (pp. 93-94) of Boyd and Vandenberghe [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729014/40119).

---

Here is a proof in the special case that $\| \cdot \|$ is the $\ell_2$-norm.

Note that $\nabla f(x) = x$.  When you set the gradient equal to $0$, you get $y - x = 0$, or $x = y$.  Thus $f^*(y) = y^T y - \|y\|^2/2 = \|y\|^2/2$.

Comment: In my question $\|x\|$ is not necessary the 2-norm. It is any arbitrary norm. That's why I was having trouble.

Comment: hmm, do you know that there is a closed form expression for the conjugate in that case?

Comment: For the conjugate of only $\|x\|$, there is a closed form expression. Doesn't the square on the norm change things (if you look at my gradient).

Comment: Yes, I agree the square on the norm changes things; I know the conjugate of a norm is the indicator function for the dual norm unit ball, but I don't know a closed form expression for the conjugate of the square of a norm.  (Except for the 2-norm.)  Hopefully somebody else will have an answer.

Answer (score 1):

My friend Hrushikesha and I think in the following way -

$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}\parallel x \parallel ^2$

$f^*(y)=\sup_x(x^Ty-\frac{1}{2}\parallel x \parallel ^2 ) $

From Hölder's inequality ,

$x^Ty \leq \parallel x \parallel \parallel y \parallel_*$ where, $\parallel  y\parallel_*$ is dual norm.

$ \Rightarrow  \sup_x(x^Ty-\frac{1}{2}\parallel x \parallel ^2 ) \leq \sup_x (\parallel x \parallel \parallel y \parallel_* - \frac{1}{2}\parallel x \parallel ^2) = \sup_{\parallel x \parallel} (\parallel x \parallel \parallel y \parallel_* - \frac{1}{2}\parallel x \parallel ^2)$

$ = \frac{1}{2}\parallel y \parallel_* ^2$

For a particular $y$ there is $x$ for which $x^Ty = \parallel x \parallel \parallel y \parallel_*$

Thus, $f^*(y)= \frac{1}{2}\parallel y \parallel_* ^2$

Answer (score -1):

This problem can be solved by completing the squares.

$$f^{∗}(y)=\max_x y^Tx−f(x)$$
$$f^{∗}(y)=\max_x ( y^Tx−||x||^2/2)$$
$$f^{∗}(y)=\max_x (y^Tx−||x||^2/2 - ||y||_{*}^2/2 + ||y||_{*}^2/2)$$
$$f^{∗}(y)\leq\max_x (||y||_{*}^2/2 - (||x||-||y||_{*})^2/2)$$
trivially, $f^{∗}(y)= ||y||_{*}^2/2$.

Comment: Is this true if $\|x\|$ is just any norm - not just the 2-norm?

Comment: In my question $\|x\|$ is not necessary the 2-norm. It is any arbitrary norm. That's why I was having trouble.

Comment: This is true for 2 norm only.