# Find the dual problem of $\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

> Find the dual problem of
> $$\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$$

I've tried the following but got stuck
$$\min_x\{||x-a_1||+||x-a_2||+||x-a_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\}=\min_{x,z_i}\{||z_1||+||z_2||+||z_3||,a_i\in\mathbb{R}^n\,z_i=x-a_i\}$$
and the Lagrangian is:\
$L(x,z,\lambda)=  ||z_1||+||z_2||+||z_3||+\sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i(z_i-x+a_i)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}z_i\lambda_i+||z_i||-x\sum\lambda_i+\sum\lambda_ia_i$

from $-x\sum\lambda_i$ we can deduce that $\sum \lambda_i=0$ else we get $-\infty$.
Now when I try to solve for each $z_i$ I get $\frac{\partial L}{\partial z_i}=\lambda_i+\frac{z_i}{||z_i||}=0$
and I'm not sure how to continue from here.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the request of the host, I propose here an answer without using the notion of conjugate function. However I have to admit that the idea behind the computations is of conjugate function.

---

Recall that the Lagrangian function is
\begin{align}
L(x,z,\lambda)=\sum_{i=1}^{3} \langle z_i,\lambda_i\rangle +||z_i||-\langle x, \sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i\rangle +\sum_{i=1}^3 \langle \lambda_i, a_i\rangle,
\end{align}
where $x, z_i, \lambda_i \in \mathbb R^n$ for $i=1,2,3$.

We claim that the dual problem is

> $$\sup_{\lambda} \inf_{x,z} L(x,z,\lambda)
> =\sup_{\lambda\in D} \sum_{i=1}^3 \langle \lambda_i, a_i\rangle. \label{eq1} \tag{1}$$

where
\begin{align}
D=\{\lambda=(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3): \sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i=0 \text{ and }
||\lambda_i||_*\leq 1 \text{ for } i=1,2,3\}.
\end{align}
Here $||\cdot||_*$ is the dual norm of $||\cdot||$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and defined as
\begin{align}
||u||_*:=\sup_{||v||\leq 1} \langle u,v\rangle.
\end{align}

---

**Proof of \eqref{eq1}.**

We now focus on $\inf_{x,z} L(x,z, \lambda)$.
We claim that
$$
\inf_x -\langle x, \sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i\rangle =
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } \sum_{i=1}^3\lambda_i=0,\\
-\infty, & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\label{eq2} \tag{2}$$
and
$$
\inf_{z_i} \langle z_i, \lambda_i \rangle +||z_i||=
\begin{cases}
0,       & \text{ if } ||\lambda_i||_* \leq 1,\\
-\infty, & \text{ if } ||\lambda_i||_* > 1.
\end{cases}
\label{eq3} \tag{3}
$$

If \eqref{eq2} and \eqref{eq3} hold true, we obtain the dual problem \eqref{eq1}.
Since the host already know how to prove \eqref{eq2}, we now only concentrate on \eqref{eq3}.

To simplify the notations, in \eqref{eq3} we shall remove the index $i$, i.e.
we are going to prove
$$
\inf_{z} \langle z, \lambda\rangle +||z||=
\begin{cases}
0,       & \text{ if } ||\lambda||_* \leq 1,\\
-\infty, & \text{ if } ||\lambda||_* > 1.
\end{cases}
\textbf{ for $z, \lambda$ are in $\mathbb R^n$ from here on.}
\label{eq4} \tag{4}
$$

Let $\lambda'=-\lambda$, we have
$$\inf_{z} \langle z, \lambda\rangle +||z||=-\sup_{z} \langle z, \lambda'\rangle -||z||.$$

**Case 1.** If $||\lambda'||_*\leq 1$, we have
$$\sup_{z} \langle \frac{z}{||z||}, \lambda'\rangle \leq ||\lambda'||_*\leq 1.$$
Here the first inequality holds due to the definition of dual norm.
Thus
$$\sup_{z} \langle z, \lambda'\rangle -||z||\leq 0.$$
Furthermore, the equality holds if we take $z=0$.

**Case 2.** If $||\lambda'||_*> 1$, from the definition of dual norm,
we deduce the existence of some $z$ such that $||z||\leq 1$
and $\langle z,\lambda'\rangle >1$.
Now, we have
$$\sup_{t\in \mathbb R} \langle tz, \lambda'\rangle-||tz||
=\sup_{t\in \mathbb R} t(  \langle z, \lambda'\rangle-||z||) =+\infty.$$

Note that $||\lambda'||_*=||\lambda||_*$, all together tell us that \eqref{eq4} is true.

Hence, \eqref{eq1} is true.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate this

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: maybe you could take a look here?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3972913/find-a-dual-problem-with-one-dual-decision-variable-to-the-problem-of-finding-th?noredirect=1#comment8196950_3972913

Answer (score 1):

Based on your arguments, the remainder is to pay attention to the following quantity,
\begin{align}
F(\lambda)=\inf_{z\in \mathbb R^n} (\langle z, \lambda \rangle +||z||).
\end{align}

This quantity can be quantified using the notion of conjugate function. Recall that the conjugate function of $f$, denoted by $f^*$, is defined by
\begin{align}
f^*(y)=\sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} (\langle x, y \rangle -f(x)).
\end{align}

Now, $F(\lambda)$ can be rewritten in term of conjugate function of $f(x)=||x||$ as follows
\begin{align}
F(\lambda) & =\inf_{z\in \mathbb R^n} (-\langle z, -\lambda \rangle +f(z))\\
           & = - \sup_{z\in \mathbb R^n} (\langle z, -\lambda \rangle - f(z))\\
           & = - f^*(-\lambda).
\end{align}
Here, in the case $f(x)=||x||$, $f^*$ is
\begin{align}
f^*(\lambda)=
\begin{cases}
0, & \text{ if } ||\lambda||_*\leq 1.\\
+\infty, & \text{ if } ||\lambda||_*> 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Where $||\cdot||_*$ is the dual norm of $||\cdot||$. To see how to obtain such formula for $f^*$, see the [first answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578439/conjugates-of-norms).

Comment: I'm not familiar with conjugate function

Comment: In my answer, the conjugate function is defined explicitly in term of dual norm. I hope that know about it. Anyway, in most of duality results in optimization, conjugate function is the main tool!

Comment: We haven't learnt this yet and I guess in more advanced courses I will.Can you solve this only with norm duality and from where I stopped or give some hint??